# Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message

Tags: php

Проблема с СМС модулем. Модуль ставил не я, но как говорят всё работало, а потом такая вот ошибка:

> `'Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'sms16::send - ' in /var/www/websty/data/www/xn--56-glc6aobv.xn--p1ai/components/registration/model.php:153 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/websty/data/www/xn--56-glc6aobv.xn--p1ai/components/registration/model.php(131): sms16->decodeResponse('<?xml version="...', 'sms16::send') #1 /var/www/websty/data/www/xn--56-glc6aobv.xn--p1ai/components/registration/model.php(276): sms16->request('sms16::send', 'https://xml.sms...', '<?xml version="...') #2 /var/www/websty/data/www/xn--56-glc6aobv.xn--p1ai/components/registration/frontend.php(274): sms16->send(Array) #3 [internal function]: registration() #4 /var/www/websty/data/www/xn--56-glc6aobv.xn--p1ai/core/cms.php(1610): call_user_func('registration') #5 /var/www/websty/data/www/xn--56-glc6aobv.xn--p1ai/index.php(90): cmsCore->proceedBody() #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/websty/data/www/xn--56-glc6aobv.xn--p1ai/components/registration/model.php on line 153`

Вот что на 153 строке:

```
throw new Exception( $method . ' - ' . $Result->response->error->value );
```

Что может быть?

Comment: Что за CMS?

Comment: InstantCMS

Comment: Данное исключение вбрасывается при определенном условии, напишите условие пожалуйста.

Comment: Проблема в обработке xml запроса на смс-биллинг.